# Batch renaming specific text within folder name

Tags: scripts, rename

Is there a way to change capitalisation of text for folders, but leave text within brackets unchanged? Is there a possible way to do this pyRenamer?

For example, if folders are named:

```
dogs bark - cats miaow [DBCM001]
james peach - jack beanstalk [JPJB521]
small pond - big fish (revive) [FIN07CD]
```

Change to:

```
Dogs Bark - Cats Miaow [DBCM001]
James Peach - Jack Beanstalk [JPJB521]
Small Pond - Big Fish (revive) [FIN07CD]
```

All wording within brackets are inconsistent. There are 1000+ folders to rename!

How could I do that?

Comment: How about text in parentheses? You haven't changed *revive* in your example, is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `rename`:

```
$ rename -n 's/(?<![([])(\b\w)/uc($1)/eg' */
dogs bark - cats miaow [DBCM001]/ -> Dogs Bark - Cats Miaow [DBCM001]/
james peach - jack beanstalk [JPJB521]/ -> James Peach - Jack Beanstalk [JPJB521]/
small pond - big fish (revive) [FIN07CD]/ -> Small Pond - Big Fish (revive) [FIN07CD]/
```

The `-n` makes `rename` print what it would do without actually doing anything. Remove the `-n` once you're sure it works as you want it to.

The `s/from/to/` is the substitution operator and will replace `from` with `to`.  Here, I am giving it:

- `(?<![([])` : this is called a [negative lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). The general format is `(?<!foo)` and it means "ignore any matches if the previous word is `foo`". Here, I am giving it the patern `[([]`, this is a character class (defined by `[ ]`) consisting of tho characters: `[` and `(`. So the whole thing means "ignore any matches that come right after a `[` or a `(`.
- `(\b\w)`:  the `\b` matches a ["word boundary"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). This is a 0-length anchor that matches the point of transition  between a word and a non-word. So, for example, it matches at the beginning of the line, or at a space, or at any other non-word character. The `\w`, on the other hand, matches a word character. So, `\b\w` matches the 1st letter of a word. The parentheses around it "capture" it so we can refer to it as `$1` on the right hand side of the substitution operator.
- `uc($1)`: this is what we replace what we matched with. As explained above, because the match is in parentheses, we can now refer to it as `$1`. `uc()` is a Perl function that makes things UPPER CASE. So this just means "print the match in capitals".
- `eg` : these are switches affecting the behavior of `s///`. Specifically, the `e` allows executing commands in the right hand side, which lets us use `uc()` and the `g` applies the substitution globally, to all matches on the line.

Finally, `*/` means "run the command on all directories in the current directory".

---

If you also want to capitalize words in parentheses, you can use this instead:

```
$ rename -n 's/(?<!\[)(\b\w)/uc($1)/eg' */
dogs bark - cats miaow [DBCM001] -> Dogs Bark - Cats Miaow [DBCM001]
james peach - jack beanstalk [JPJB521] -> James Peach - Jack Beanstalk [JPJB521]
small pond - big fish (revive) [FIN07CD] -> Small Pond - Big Fish (Revive) [FIN07CD]
```

Comment: Too bad, I *so* wanted to use Parameter Expansion like `${a^}`, but it's just not applicable without an overkill solution here…

Comment: @dessert like this? `for d in */; do newName=""; while read -a name; do for word in "${name[@]}"; do newName="$newName ${word^}"; done; done <<<"$d"; echo "$newName"; done`

Comment: Exactly! Compared to the neat `rename` solution that's an overkill.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the quick response! I'll give it a try... I'm not clued up in the realms of code at all. I'll be sure to have a bash though as your instruction seems pretty self explanatory. And yes, text unchanged in parenthesis was intentional.

Comment: @terdon Having successfully renamed a bunch of files, I have a folder containing something similar: 

DOGS BARK - CATS MIAOW [DBCM001]
JAMES PEACH - JACK BEANSTALK [JPJB521]
SMALL POND - BIG FISH (REVIVE) [FIN07CD]

Need to change to:

Dogs Bark - Cats Miaow [DBCM001]
James Peach - Jack Beanstalk [JPJB521]
Small Pond - Big Fish (revive) [FIN07CD]

Being new to script & code, I have again searched for a solution with limited success and thought it prudent to save time and return for some assistance...
This topic can then happily be closed.

Comment: @user779373 "closing" is done here by [accepting an answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers), whihc you can do by clicking on the check mark to the left. You seem to now be asking a completely different question: you have allcaps names and want to change to 1st letter capitalization but, this time, also including any words in parentheses. If so, you can try `rename -n 's/(?<![([])(\b\w)(.*?)\b/uc($1) . lc($2)/eg' */`. Please ask a new question if you need more help.

Comment: @terdon - Ah OK. Thanks again for your script wisdom, your suggestion works, much appreciated.